# how to output an interval field in coldfusion

Tags: intervals, cfoutput

I have an interval field in a table for the timecard application. the field will calculate total work time of a user by using punch out time minus punch in time. I take a total of total work time in a week for a user and in my postgressql database it will show 40:30:22 (as in 40 hours 30 minutes and 22 seconds).
When i do cfoutput for that field, it becomes: 0 years 0mons 0days 40 hours 30 minutes 22 seconds.
Is There a way for it to just show 40:30:22 ?
Thank you,

Comment: NVM. I found the way to do it. use to_char format in postgressql when query it out. something like below: select  to_char(sum(totaltime2),'hh24:mi:ss')  as totalofmonth
  from timesheet

Comment: If you think the solution would be helpful to others, please post it as an "answer". Answering your own question is allowed on S.O.